# Problems with supporting tablets and handsets simultaneously - localisation

Tags: listview, localization, hebrew, android

I support different languages in my application and also allow the user to swap languages within the application itself. I noticed some problems a few weeks ago with users on version 7 of the SDK having the Hebrew language so I withdrew support for anything before version 8. I therefore stored the strings file in **values-he-v8**. However, when I swap to Hebrew on my tablet it doesn't change the language (this works fine on my phone). Why? I thought this should be all versions above version 8. Changing to Dutch (NL - I just have a values-nl directory) works as on the phone. Here is my changeLocale method:

```
    public void changeLocale(String language) {
        Locale locale;
        if (language.equals("default")) {
            locale = Locale.getDefault();
        } else {
            locale = new Locale(language);
        }
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());   
    }
```

Likewise I've noticed that in my ListView for displaying the scores will display Hebrew names okay on my phone. They are still left-aligned with their rank in the score tables, a full stop and then the name. E.g. 50. יניב

On the tablet, however, the whole string gets pushed to the right and becomes *name* .50

This is the relevant code in my ScoreArrayAdapter used to populate the ListView:

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(layoutRow, null, true);

        TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.TextView_PlayerName);
        name.setText(values.get(position).rank.toString() + ". "
        + values.get(position).playerName);
        ...
```

I've now solved this second issue by creating separate textviews for the rank and the player name (although technically this is probably now backwards to Israeli readers). But I've still no idea why my file which should work for all SDKs 8+ is not working on my v3.1 tablet.